# Why I can't apply clickhouse json functions for "FORMAT JSON" query results?

Tags: clickhouse

I made a simple query to test JSONExtractRaw function, but with no luck:

> select JSONExtractRaw(j, 'data') from (select * from devices
> format JSON) as j;

But it doesn't work because of "Syntax error". Is that a bug or this is expected?

Comment: It is expected behavior - FORMAT-clause can be applied only to the external SELECT-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [v20.7.2.30](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/#clickhouse-release-v20-7-2-30-stable-2020-08-31) were added functions that format SQL outputs - [formatRow](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#formatrow) and [formatRowNoNewline](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#formatrownonewline):

```sql
SELECT JSONExtractRaw(j, 'data') AS json
FROM 
(
    SELECT formatRow('JSONEachRow', *) AS j
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM 
        (
            /* emulate the test dataset */
            SELECT 
                1 AS id,
                '[{"a": 8}]' AS data
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                2 AS id,
                '[{"a": 2}]' AS data
        )
    )
)

┌─json───────────┐
│ "[{\"a\": 8}]" │
│ "[{\"a\": 2}]" │
└────────────────┘
```